# Can't Enable-Migrations. Throws System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I can't enable EF migrations!

Using the package manager console, it throws the following:

`PM> Enable-Migrations
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyApp' or one of its dependencies. Index not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131124)
File name: 'MyApp' ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Index not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131124)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.LoadAssembly()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindType[TBase](String typeName, Func`2 filter, Func`2 noType, Func`3 multipleTypes, Func`3 noTypeWithName, Func`3 multipleTypesWithName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.GetContextTypeRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MyApp' or one of its dependencies. Index not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131124)
```

Also:
1. My default project (in the PM CONSOLE) is 'MyApp'
2. The solution only has 'MyApp' 
3. The class inheriting from DbContext is in 'MyApp.Models'
4. I also tried creating a new solution and then copy pasted all classes to it and it threw the same error

What is happening?
I once enabled migrations in this project in the past, but two days later I deleted all migration stuff from it because it wasn't necesary. But now I really need them

Comment: if you had removed all migrations classes, did you delete the records in __MigrationHistory table.
Try to use a clean new database, to see if problem still exits. most likely you have removed all your migration in your code base but your database still have the records ealier

Comment: I have deleted the database several times and started with a fresh new generated database several times. So this is not the problem

Comment: Similar issue (different cause): http://stackoverflow.com/q/23666716/176877

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what the problem was!

What I did was create a whole new solution. Then I started to copy/paste/"Include in Project" every .cs from the original solution. With every paste I tried to run the "Enable-Migrations" command. With every paste it was working fine until I found the problematic .cs that caused that Enable-Migrations didn't run.

Then, inside the problematic .cs (which was a Controller), I started isolating code to see what was causing the problem.

This was the code that made the difference (Enable-Migrations ok vs badimageformatexception etc etc)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// GET: /MessagesAjax/SendWithInetlab/?to=56995189711&body=bla
    /// </summary>
    [JsonHandleError]
    public JsonResult SendWithInetlab(string to, string body) // TODO: Delete
    {
        Inetlab.SMPP.SmppClient client = new Inetlab.SMPP.SmppClient();
        client.Connect("200.54.98.222", 54002);

        // TODO: test
        if (client.Status == Inetlab.SMPP.Common.ConnectionStatus.Open)
        {
            client.Bind("blah", "pwd", Inetlab.SMPP.Common.ConnectionMode.Transmitter);

            if (client.Status == Inetlab.SMPP.Common.ConnectionStatus.Bound)
            {
                IList<SubmitSmResp> respList = client.Submit(
                    SMS.ForSubmit().From("56951000001").To(to).Text(body)
                    );

                client.UnBind();
            }
            client.Disconnect();
        }

        return Json("bla", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Weird!  I find it works well to have a project for my POCO entities and another for my `DbContext` and configuration and migrations classes.  Doing that might help avoid bonkers errors like this in the future.

Comment: You mean to isolate Controller classes in one project and "Model" classes (+ DbContext) in other project? Wouldn't that be against MVC itself? I mean: I would end up having one "M" project, and one "VC" project

Comment: Good question. Recently I've tended towards creating numerous projects (and hence assemblies) for a reasonably big project. It seems to be good practise. Here you would create one project for your EF "model" classes - the entities themselves - and it would ideally have no dependency on the EF assemblies. You'd create another project that references it for the EF-dependent bits. Then you would reference *both* from your MVC project...

Comment: What would this give you? Well, for one thing it would avoid the problems you're having here. But it would also give you more flexibility in the future. Say you want to write a small tool for an administrator to run on the server to clean up the database. You could re-use your model and EF assemblies in a console app. Or say you want to write a Windows Store app version of the program: you could put your model in a portable class library and use it in the client code too! (This link - http://forums.asp.net/t/1683781.aspx/1 - shows that it's not crazy to separate out your model classes)

Comment: Ahh thank you! Then I might do that, because I'm planning to have a worker role (azure terminology) and this would certainly need to reuse the Model (because this worker needs to use the database too, as the web role does)

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same problem.

The reason for the `System.BadImageFormatException` was because I had a dependency on an x64 DLL (`Magick.NET-x64.dll` in my case). Forcing the project to build in 32-bit solved it.

1. Select your **WebProject**
2. Go to **Properties**
3. Select the **Build** tab
4. Change the **Platform target**: from **x64** to **Any CPU**

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Sometimes x64 is needed and you can't use Any CPU.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the current output folder of your project. 
When changing the target platform to x64 the output folder also changes to bin\x64\Debug.
This seemed to be a problem for the enable-migrations cmdlet. 
After changing the output folder back to bin\Debug for a x64 platform build everything works fine.

found at: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/438488

Answer (score 0):

I have some things that may help you...

[This](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/438488)
 post has a similar exception.

And [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx) suggest similar issues (see remarks at the bottom).

If I were you I would try following the steps in the other post and maybe "Clean Solution" as well. It seems to me that the PM is having trouble executing the cmdlet because of something similar to that post so I would check all the settings under MyApp.Properties.

Hope you find a solution.

Comment: Can I tell "enable-migrations" or "update-database" where to look for the dll of my project?

Comment: I tried what was told in the first link ("This post has a similar exception") and some variants of it, but didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- check that all projects in your solution that reference Entity Framework reference the same version,
- unload any projects that do not contain code for your application, e.g. setup/deployment or documentation projects, and
- temporarily disable any Visual Studio add-ons.

Then restart Visual Studio and execute the command again.  Also, see if running VS as an administrator helps.

Comment: (1) I only have one project in my solution, (2) Idem, (3) Like which add-on? I will try, although I've never installed any add ons (is NuGet an addon?)

Comment: Try to identify whether this is a problem with your VS installation or with your code.  To do that, create an empty console app with the default settings.  Install the EF NuGet package, and create a minimal `DbContext` and a sample entity with just one property.  Add code to the main method that instantiates the context and executes a query.  Check it runs.  Can you enable migrations?

Comment: If it works, you have a problem with the code or settings in your other project.  If the test fails, try repairing your VS installation.

Comment: Its not a problem with my VS installation because I've already tried running Enable-Migrations on empty projects and it works fine. It is indeed a problem with my project configuration/settings.

Comment: Did the suggestions from @DaveWilliams help?  Check the output directory for the project containing the `DbContext`.  Is it `bin\Debug` or `bin\x??\Debug`?  The latter seems not to play well with migrations.

Comment: Please tell us a bit more about your project/solution.  What settings have you changed from the defaults?